# MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to 34.231.146.63:27017 closed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native

I am trying to update this 2 document in my MongoDB via mongoose. Basically, I am trying to simulate a seat reservation flow by a student. When the student reserves a seat, the underlined fields for both of the documents should get updated.

[image]

[image]

My code for updating the document fields:

client-side code:

```
const onDialogOKPressed = async (contextStudySpace) => {
    setPopUpDialogState(false);

    //current data and time
    const date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
    const time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
      hour12: false,
      hour: "numeric",
      minute: "numeric",
    });

    //make a student object
    const student = {
      profImg: studentData.profImg,
      seatStat: "Pending Reservation_Area 5B_" + seatSelection + "_" + time,
      checkInEndTime: calcCheckInEndTime(
        time,
        customization.revCheckInTimeLimit
      ),
      shortBreakEndTime: "",
      longBreakEndTime: "",
      delayed: false,
      reserveNum: studentData.reserveNum,
      timeline: studentData.timeline,
      dinnerBreakCount: studentData.dinnerBreakCount,
      lunchBreakCount: studentData.lunchBreakCount,
      shortBreakCount: studentData.shortBreakCount,
    };

    fetch("http://192.168.0.160:4000/api/studentData/" + studentData._id, {
      method: "PATCH",
      body: JSON.stringify(student), //changes the object into a json string
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${studentUser.token}`,
      },
    })
      .then(async (response) => {
        try {
          const json = await response.json();

          if (response.status === 200) {
            //dispatchStudentData({ type: "EDIT_STUDENT", payload: json });
          } else {
            //if there is no user, which means got error ..
            //toast message
            ToastAndroid.showWithGravityAndOffset(
              json.error,
              ToastAndroid.LONG,
              ToastAndroid.BOTTOM,
              0,
              250
            );
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    //UPDATE STUDY SPACE
    const newData = contextStudySpace
      .find((s) => s._id === "64920cfad8f08d6d10277fbd")
      .data.map((obj) =>
        obj.seat === seatSelection
          ? {
              ...obj,
              status: "Reserved",
              userInfo: studentData.username,
            }
          : obj
      );

    

    console.log(
      "GET AVAILABLE SEATS: " +
        contextStudySpace.find((s) => s._id === "64920cfad8f08d6d10277fbd")
          .availableSeats
    );
    //make a study space object
    const studyObj = {
      availableSeats:
        contextStudySpace.find((s) => s._id === "64920cfad8f08d6d10277fbd")
          .availableSeats - 1,
      data: newData,
    };

    //get study space id
    const sID = contextStudySpace.find(
      (s) => s._id === "64920cfad8f08d6d10277fbd"
    )._id;

    fetch("http://192.168.0.160:4000/api/studySpace/" + sID, {
      method: "PATCH",
      body: JSON.stringify(studyObj), //changes the object into a json string
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then(async (response) => {
        try {
          const json = await response.json();

          if (response.status === 200) {
            //dispatch({ type: "EDIT_STUDYSPACE", payload: json });
            //finally...
            //clear seat selection
            setSeatSelection("");

            ToastAndroid.showWithGravityAndOffset(
              "Seat reserved successfully.",
              ToastAndroid.LONG,
              ToastAndroid.BOTTOM,
              0,
              250
            );

            //naivate back to home page
            navigation.navigate("Home");
          } else {
            ToastAndroid.showWithGravityAndOffset(
              json.error,
              ToastAndroid.LONG,
              ToastAndroid.BOTTOM,
              0,
              250
            );
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

server-side code:

```
const updateStudent = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const {
    name,
    email,
    phoneNumber,
    gender,
    birthday,
    school,
    profImg,
    reserveNum,
    violateNum,
    blacklistNum,
    authStat,
    seatStat,
    checkInEndTime,
    shortBreakEndTime,
    longBreakEndTime,
    delayed,
    timeline,
    shortBreakCount,
    lunchBreakCount,
    dinnerBreakCount,
  } = req.body; //extract the data that comes with the request

  console.log("here ");

  //make sure it is a valid type of id (mongodb type of id)
  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    //if its not valid
    return res.status(404).json({ error: "Invalid student ID." });
  }

  //check if seatStat is empty (= updated from admin side)
  if (!seatStat) {
    console.log("here admin");

    const student = await Student.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: id },
      {
        $set: {
          name: name,
          email: email,
          phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
          gender: gender,
          birthday: birthday,
          school: school,
          violateNum: violateNum,
          blacklistNum: blacklistNum,
          authStat: authStat,
        },
      }
    ); //returns the to be updated student

    if (!student) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "No such student found." });
    }

    //res.status(200).json(admin); //return the to be updated admin

    const students = await Student.find();

    res.status(200).json(students);
  } else {
    //updated from student side

    console.log("here student"); // THIS GETS EXECUTED..

    const student = await Student.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: id },
      {
        $set: {
          profImg: profImg,
          seatStat: seatStat,
          checkInEndTime: checkInEndTime,
          shortBreakEndTime: shortBreakEndTime,
          longBreakEndTime: longBreakEndTime,
          delayed: delayed,
          reserveNum: reserveNum,
          timeline: timeline,
          shortBreakCount: shortBreakCount,
          lunchBreakCount: lunchBreakCount,
          dinnerBreakCount: dinnerBreakCount,
        },
      }
    ); //returns the to be updated student

//THIS PART BELOW DOES NOT GETS EXECUTED..

    console.log("student out here....");

    if (!student) {
      console.log("No such student found1.");
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "No such student found." });
    }

    console.log("find by id such that id is...." + id);

    //find the updated student
    const studentUpdated = await Student.findById(id);

    if (!studentUpdated) {
      console.log("No such student found2.");
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "No such student found." });
    }

    console.log("student found.");
    res.status(200).json(studentUpdated);
  }
};
```

As a result, only the study space data gets updated, but the student data remains intact..

Below was the error I got when the code tried to update the student data. FYI: the new student data values can reach the updateStudent function in the server, but kind of gets stuck at the findOneAndUpdate() function? My server crashed after awhile (it did not crash immediately) and after I restart the server, I can see the patch request for the student data being started again, but after awhile the server crashes again with the same error.

[image]

**Note:** My code for updating study space and student data was working yesterday. But it suddenly failed today. I am also unsure what is this address `34.231.146.63` in the error message?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551